# DPAN to create local CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan, dpan

I want to make a CPAN repository from all curently installed modules. So I used autobundle to get a list of installed modules.
I then used BackPAN::Index to download all the distributions into a directory and then ran dpan in it.
It chew them for quite some time and then failed

```
    MyCPAN::App::DPAN::Indexer 1.28
    Processing 2 distributions
    One * = 1 distribution
    # Extracting with ->_untar_at
    # Extraction succeeded
    +# Extracting with ->_untar_at
    # Extraction succeeded
    ++
    /home/ec2-user/dpan_test/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz-8496-trial has a problem and I have to abort:
    Deleting file (unless you're debugging)
    Some distributions in the repository do not show up in the file
            /home/ec2-user/dpan_test/Moose-1.24.tar.gz
            /home/ec2-user/dpan_test/Moose-Autobox-0.11.tar.gz at /usr/local/share/perl5/MyCPAN/App/DPAN/Reporter/Minimal.pm line 439
Some distributions in the repository do not show up in the file
```

and list of every distribution follows.

OTOH I have a success logged for every file in the indexer_reports.

Output from perl -V on [this Pastie link](http://pastie.org/2391009)

Comment: What happens when you run this under debugging, and what's your configuration? Can you show me the first part of the packages file it creates?

Comment: I ran with debug level logging and updated the question with the log output (only with 2 distros so that it does not take hours). Also added 'perl -V' info.

Comment: Also, send me one of the indexer reports. If you'd rather talk to me in private email about it, use the email address in the span docs :)

Comment: The perl config doesn't interest me as much as those other things. Also, I might have fixed this in the newer versions in the github repo.

Comment: I sent you an email with the indexer log.

Comment: I need to see your config file, too.

Comment: My config contains only this one line "alarm 600". I also sent it yesterday in an email (it was in a zip file with other files).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as well.

Comment: so what was the outcome? Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No I did not - I gave up on dpan.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same error it was resolved when I added:

organize_dists 1

Though when trying attempting to install from the mirror CPAN fails as no 01mailrc.txt.gz file can be found. This can be overcome by copying the file from say http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz into the new mirror's authors directory

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, but could fix it:

In my case, I put the tgz file directly in the root of my dpan directory. Moving "./dpan/DateTime-0.70.tar.gz" to "./dpan/authors/id/D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-0.70.tar.gz" did fix the problem. Now "02packages.details.txt.gz" and "03modlist.data.gz" get created.